# i use distinct but there is a duplicate sql help me

Tags: sql

```
select distinct  WORKORDER.WONUM ,  WORKORDER.SVCGRP ,WORKORDER.STATUS ,
WORKORDER.DESCRIPTION ,WORKORDER.REPORTDATE WO_DATE ,RFQLINE.ENTERDATE RFQ_DATE,
PRLINE.RFQNUM,PRLINE.PONUM ,PRLINE.prnum  ,PRLINE.ENTERDATE PR_DATE,POLINE.ENTERDATE
from workorder 
join PRLINE on workorder.wonum = prline.refwo 
JOIN RFQLINE ON  workorder.wonum =rfqline.refwo 
JOIN POLINE ON  workorder.wonum =PoLine.refwo 
where  WORKORDER.REPORTDATE between ('12/dec/12') and ('1/mar/15')
and WORKORDER.STATUS NOT IN ( 'CLOSE', 'CAN')
and WORKORDER.GLACCOUNT like '%ACAD-C0';



1730382 43  WMATL   CUSC User Issues,Civil  09-JAN-13   15-NOV-14   4122    3624    3754    15-JAN-13   23-DEC-14
1730382 43  WMATL   CUSC User Issues,Civil  09-JAN-13   15-NOV-14   4122    3624    3754    15-JAN-13   23-DEC-14
1730382 43  WMATL   CUSC User Issues,Civil  09-JAN-13   15-NOV-14   4122    3624    3754    15-JAN-13   23-DEC-14
1730382 43  WMATL   CUSC User Issues,Civil  09-JAN-13   15-NOV-14   4122    3624    3754    15-JAN-13   23-DEC-14
1730382 43  WMATL   CUSC User Issues,Civil  09-JAN-13   15-NOV-14   4122    3624    3754    15-JAN-13   23-DEC-14
1730382 43  WMATL   CUSC User Issues,Civil  09-JAN-13   15-NOV-14   4122    3624    3754    15-JAN-13   23-DEC-14
1730382 43  WMATL   CUSC User Issues,Civil  09-JAN-13   15-NOV-14   4122    3624    3754    15-JAN-13   23-DEC-14
1730382 43  WMATL   CUSC User Issues,Civil  09-JAN-13   15-NOV-14   4122    3624    3754    15-JAN-13   23-DEC-14
1730382 43  WMATL   CUSC User Issues,Civil  09-JAN-13   15-NOV-14   4122    3624    3754    15-JAN-13   23-DEC-14
1730382 43  WMATL   CUSC User Issues,Civil  09-JAN-13   15-NOV-14   4122    3624    3754    15-JAN-13   23-DEC-14
1730382 43  WMATL   CUSC User Issues,Civil  09-JAN-13   15-NOV-14   4122    3624    3754    15-JAN-13   23-DEC-14
1730382 43  WMATL   CUSC User Issues,Civil  09-JAN-13   15-NOV-14   4122    3624    3754    15-JAN-13   23-DEC-14
2899705 40  WMATL   Academic User Issues,OTHERS 15-JAN-14   04-JAN-15   4171    3648    5073    28-JAN-14   11-JAN-15
2899705 40  WMATL   Academic User Issues,OTHERS 15-JAN-14   04-JAN-15   4171    3648    5073    28-JAN-14   11-JAN-15
2899705 40  WMATL   Academic User Issues,OTHERS 15-JAN-14   04-JAN-15   4171    3648    5073    28-JAN-14   11-JAN-15
2899705 40  WMATL   Academic User Issues,OTHERS 15-JAN-14   04-JAN-15   4171    3648    5073    28-JAN-14   11-JAN-15
2899705 40  WMATL   Academic User Issues,OTHERS 15-JAN-14   04-JAN-15   4171    3648    5073    28-JAN-14   11-JAN-15
2899705 40  WMATL   Academic User Issues,OTHERS 15-JAN-14   04-JAN-15   4171    3648    5073    28-JAN-14   11-JAN-15
2899705 40  WMATL   Academic User Issues,OTHERS 15-JAN-14   04-JAN-15   4171    3648    5073    28-JAN-14   11-JAN-15
2899705 40  WMATL   Academic User Issues,OTHERS 15-JAN-14   04-JAN-15   4171    3648    5073    28-JAN-14   11-JAN-15
2899705 40  WMATL   Academic User Issues,OTHERS 15-JAN-14   04-JAN-15   4171    3648    5073    28-JAN-14   11-JAN-15
2899705 40  WMATL   Academic User Issues,OTHERS 15-JAN-14   04-JAN-15   4171    3648    5073    28-JAN-14   11-JAN-15
2899705 40  WMATL   Academic User Issues,OTHERS 15-JAN-14   04-JAN-15   4171    3648    5073    28-JAN-14   11-JAN-15
2899705 40  WMATL   Academic User Issues,OTHERS 15-JAN-14   04-JAN-15   4171    3648    5073    28-JAN-14   11-JAN-15
2899705 40  WMATL   Academic User Issues,OTHERS 15-JAN-14   04-JAN-15   4171    3648    5073    28-JAN-14   11-JAN-15
2899705 40  WMATL   Academic User Issues,OTHERS 15-JAN-14   04-JAN-15   4171    3648    5073    28-JAN-14   11-JAN-15
2899705 40  WMATL   Academic User Issues,OTHERS 15-JAN-14   04-JAN-15   4171    3648    5073    28-JAN-14   11-JAN-15
2899705 40  WMATL   Academic User Issues,OTHERS 15-JAN-14   04-JAN-15   4171    3648    5073    28-JAN-14   11-JAN-15
2899981 41  APPR    Academic User Issues,WATER PROOFING 25-JAN-14   14-SEP-14   4010    3489    5080    02-FEB-14   21-SEP-14
2900868 42  WMATL   Academic User Issues,WATER PROOFING 16-FEB-14   12-OCT-14   4065    3554    5148    25-FEB-14   02-NOV-14
2900868 42  WMATL   Academic User Issues,WATER PROOFING 16-FEB-14   12-OCT-14   4065    3554    5148    25-FEB-14   02-NOV-14
2900868 42  WMATL   Academic User Issues,WATER PROOFING 16-FEB-14   12-OCT-14   4065    3554    5148    25-FEB-14   02-NOV-14
3073377 41  WMATL   Academic User Issues,OTHERS 26-FEB-14   24-APR-14   3761    3600    5199    13-MAR-14   09-DEC-14
3073377 41  WMATL   Academic User Issues,OTHERS 26-FEB-14   24-APR-14   3761    3600    5199    13-MAR-14   09-DEC-14
3073377 41  WMATL   Academic User Issues,OTHERS 26-FEB-14   24-APR-14   3761    3600    5199    13-MAR-14   09-DEC-14
3073377 41  WMATL   Academic User Issues,OTHERS 26-FEB-14   24-APR-14   3761    3600    5199    13-MAR-14   09-DEC-14
3073383 41  WMATL   Academic User Issues,OTHERS 26-FEB-14   24-APR-14   3778    3601    5197    13-MAR-14   09-DEC-14
3073383 41  WMATL   Academic User Issues,OTHERS 26-FEB-14   24-APR-14   3778    3601    5197    13-MAR-14   09-DEC-14
3073383 41  WMATL   Academic User Issues,OTHERS 26-FEB-14   24-APR-14   3778    3601    5197    13-MAR-14   09-DEC-14
3073383 41  WMATL   Academic User Issues,OTHERS 26-FEB-14   24-APR-14   3778    3601    5197    13-MAR-14   09-DEC-14
3073388 41  WMATL   Academic User Issues,OTHERS 26-FEB-14   24-APR-14   3762    3612    5198    13-MAR-14   09-DEC-14

enter code here
```

Comment: what are these, correct the format of your question and say about an specific problem or error, it needs to be clear what you want, I mean don't post only the code, post a the description of the problem or of the what you want.

Comment: Question is not clear. Whats your problem

Comment: A query with `distinct` doesn't return duplicates, so there has to be an actual difference between the values. There seems to be some fields that are selected but missing in the result that you show.

Comment: the error is workorder.wonum it is duplicate and  i put distinct what shall i do

Comment: `DISTINCT` is **always** applied to the **entire row** - not to a single column ....

Comment: Remove the columns that are _different_ from your SELECT. Also post what kind of database. MySQL? Oracle?

Comment: ORACLE  WE USED MAXIMO APP,

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason you are seeing duplicates from the output is because you are only displaying the date without the time in your output. You probably have multiple rows for each WONUM date (WO_DATE, RFQ_DATE).

If you change your date format to include the time as well:

```
alter session set nls_date_format='dd-MON-yy hh:mi:ss AM';
```

then run your query again, you should see rows with same `WONUM` differ by the time for the same day.

If you truly want distinct value for the date only (disregarding the time) then change your query to:

```
select  distinct  WORKORDER.WONUM ,  WORKORDER.SVCGRP ,WORKORDER.STATUS ,
WORKORDER.DESCRIPTION ,trunc(WORKORDER.REPORTDATE) WO_DATE ,trunc(RFQLINE.ENTERDATE) RFQ_DATE,
PRLINE.RFQNUM,PRLINE.PONUM ,PRLINE.prnum  ,PRLINE.ENTERDATE PR_DATE,POLINE.ENTERDATE from ...
```